# Create Pandas Dataframe from Elements in List of Dicts

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have to iterate through the rows of a column (in an existing dataframe) which contains a list of dicts, and then create two new dataframes out of the data from there. The general shape of one of these lists looks like this:

```
[
 {"a": 10, "type": "square"}, {"type": "square", "b":11}, 
 {"type": "square", "c": 12}, {"d": 13, "type": "square"},
 {"type": "square", "e": 14}, {"a": 15, "type": "circle"}, 
 {"type": "circle", "b": 16}, {"type": "circle", "c": 17}, 
 {"d": 18, "type": "circle"}, {"type": "circle", "e": 19}
]
```

I have thousands of rows of these guys and want to create two new dataframes, one for circles and one for squares, resulting in a dataframe whose first row looks roughly like this:

```
      type    a  b  c  d  e
0    square   10 11 12 13 14
```

So far, I've tried converting the whole thing to json, which worked ok but seemed to change the nature of the dataframe so that it wasn't manipulable anymore. The json also created a dataframe with multiple rows (one for each element) and I wasn't able to "flatten" the dataframe onto the one key (in this case it would be "type").

I've also tried `DataFrame.from_records`, `DataFrame.from_dict`, and various, similar other ways of reading in the data using pandas with no luck.

EDIT: Sorry for being unclear,the above example of a dictionary lives in a "cell" of an existing dataframe, and I think the first step I'm looking for involves extracting it out of that "cell." So far, I've tried various ways to transform the object into something usable (like the list above), but haven't been successful. I would need to create the variable to look something like this `my_list = df.column[0]` for example, so I could then iterate over the rows.

Comment: Do you mean that the column is a list?  Or that each row contains a list like the one above?

Comment: @piRSquared Each row contains a list like the one above. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let `l` be your list of dictionaries

```
l = [
 {"a": 10, "type": "square"}, {"type": "square", "b":11}, 
 {"type": "square", "c": 12}, {"d": 13, "type": "square"},
 {"type": "square", "e": 14}, {"a": 15, "type": "circle"}, 
 {"type": "circle", "b": 16}, {"type": "circle", "c": 17}, 
 {"d": 18, "type": "circle"}, {"type": "circle", "e": 19}
]
```

Then let's define a series `s` to be 10 rows of this list

```
s = pd.Series([l] * 10)
print(s)

0    [{'type': 'square', 'a': 10}, {'type': 'square...
1    [{'type': 'square', 'a': 10}, {'type': 'square...
2    [{'type': 'square', 'a': 10}, {'type': 'square...
3    [{'type': 'square', 'a': 10}, {'type': 'square...
4    [{'type': 'square', 'a': 10}, {'type': 'square...
5    [{'type': 'square', 'a': 10}, {'type': 'square...
6    [{'type': 'square', 'a': 10}, {'type': 'square...
7    [{'type': 'square', 'a': 10}, {'type': 'square...
8    [{'type': 'square', 'a': 10}, {'type': 'square...
9    [{'type': 'square', 'a': 10}, {'type': 'square...
dtype: object
```

---

Now I'll define a function that uses a dictionary comprehension to rearrange the list to something more palatable for `pd.Series`. In fact, the keys of the dictionary will be `tuple`s so that the index of the produced series with be a `pd.MultiIndex`.  This will make it easier to break into 2 separate dataframes later.

```
def proc(l):
    return pd.Series(
        {(li['type'], k): v for li in l for k, v in li.items() if k != 'type'})
```

---

Now I use `apply`

```
df = s.apply(proc)
df

  circle                 square                
       a   b   c   d   e      a   b   c   d   e
0     15  16  17  18  19     10  11  12  13  14
1     15  16  17  18  19     10  11  12  13  14
2     15  16  17  18  19     10  11  12  13  14
3     15  16  17  18  19     10  11  12  13  14
4     15  16  17  18  19     10  11  12  13  14
5     15  16  17  18  19     10  11  12  13  14
6     15  16  17  18  19     10  11  12  13  14
7     15  16  17  18  19     10  11  12  13  14
8     15  16  17  18  19     10  11  12  13  14
9     15  16  17  18  19     10  11  12  13  14
```

---

I can assign my 2 dataframes quite easily from this point

```
circle = df.circle
square = df.square
```

---

***alternative approach***
Instead of using apply, we could use a set of comprehensions on `s`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {k: {(li['type'], k): v
         for li in l
         for k, v in li.items() if k != 'type'}
     for k, l in s.iteritems()}
).T
```

---

***timing***
The multi-comprehension approach seems faster

[image]

Comment: Thanks! As such, this works well; I wasn't super clear in my question. I'm having trouble extracting that list of dictionaries from an existing dataframe, and I'm getting "DataFrame constructor not properly called" errors. So instead of creating the variable as an existing dict, I have to do something like `new_list = data.column[0]` so I can loop through the other 15k or so rows. Thanks again, sorry for the unclear question; I'm pretty new at this.

Comment: AMAZING! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

This works for your example:

```
pd.DataFrame(myList).groupby('type').agg(lambda x: x.dropna())

         a   b   c   d   e
type                      
circle  15  16  17  18  19
square  10  11  12  13  14
```

the idea is to read in the list of dicts, convert them into a single DataFrame with one row per dict, group them by type, and then use the `agg` method to drop all missing values in each variable.

**data**

```
 myList = [
 {"a": 10, "type": "square"}, {"type": "square", "b":11}, 
 {"type": "square", "c": 12}, {"d": 13, "type": "square"},
 {"type": "square", "e": 14}, {"a": 15, "type": "circle"}, 
 {"type": "circle", "b": 16}, {"type": "circle", "c": 17}, 
 {"d": 18, "type": "circle"}, {"type": "circle", "e": 19}
]
```

---

The above answer runs into a problem if the types are repeated as in the following list:

```
myList2 = [
 {"a": 10, "type": "square"}, {"type": "square", "b":11}, 
 {"type": "square", "c": 12}, {"d": 13, "type": "square"},
 {"type": "square", "e": 14}, {"a": 15, "type": "circle"}, 
 {"type": "circle", "b": 16}, {"type": "circle", "c": 17}, 
 {"d": 18, "type": "circle"}, {"type": "circle", "e": 19},
  {"a": 11, "type": "square"}, {"type": "square", "b":12}, 
 {"type": "square", "c": 13}, {"d": 14, "type": "square"},
 {"type": "square", "e": 15}, {"a": 16, "type": "circle"}, 
 {"type": "circle", "b": 17}, {"type": "circle", "c": 18}, 
 {"d": 20, "type": "circle"}, {"type": "circle", "e": 20}
]
```

As long as the list of dicts is regular, that is, there are 5 adjacent dicts for each type, then you can add a list comprehension to the `groupby` method as follows.

```
pd.DataFrame(myList2).groupby(['type',
                               [math.floor(i / 5) for i, _ in enumerate(myList)]])
                     .agg(lambda x: x.dropna())

           a   b   c   d   e
type                        
circle 1  15  16  17  18  19
       3  16  17  18  20  20
square 0  10  11  12  13  14
       2  11  12  13  14  15
```

Comment: Thanks, will definitely give this a shot. I'm afraid that I was unclear in my original question, in that the data exists in a "cell" within a dataframe, and not explicitly as a list of dicts, and I'm having trouble getting it out of there. I get "Dataframe constructor not properly called" errors, when I try to construct the variables like so `myList = data.column[0]` (unfortunately I think I need to do it that way to iterate through the 15k or so other rows, but I'd love if you had another idea). Thanks again, sorry for the unclear question, I'm pretty new with this!